# How to build Interactive Report using master detail records

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am building an Oracle Apex 5 Interactive Report. There will be two sections - a master record section called 'Request' and a detail record section called 'Multiple Stations'. My master 'request' record type has many detail 'station' records tied to it via request_id. There can be up to 10 stations per request. My query for the 'Multiple Stations' portion is

```
select  station_number, room_number
from stations
where request_id = :P4_REQUEST_KEY
```

My form fields are P4_STATION_1, P4_ROOM_1, P4_STATION_2, P4_ROOM_2 etc. The request_key is passed in correctly.  Nothing shows up in the 'Multiple Stations' report region. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to submit value of P4_REQUEST_KEY on page load/button click ?.Please check value of  P4_REQUEST_KEY in session details. Also you will able to fetch stations details of specific Request only after page submit or region refresh .hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Amol.  I learned that I needed to have several interactive reports on the page, each in their own regions with links to their respective edit forms. E.g. one for the master record, one for comments, and one for detail records.